# Is caching thousands of user id's in session variables bad for performance in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables

If I want to cache say 2 ids in a session variable for each user and there will be a possibility of thoussands or more users online at once, will this effect my performance of the site?

Comment: if you're thinking about **thousands** of users, then use a Server Cache (like memcache or couchbase, or even Amazon/Azure Cache systems) as you will not only use it to save the user session id, but also the data from the db...

Answer (score 3):

From a memory perspective that is 2 integers (8 bytes) with 50,000 active users.  That is only 400KB.  From a speed perspective, the session is a hash table with fast lookup.  You will spend more time doing actual work than ASP.net will spend retrieving the session.

Answer (score 1):

If the session state mode is InProc than there should be no negligible impact to performance. You will notice an impact to performance if you are using a session state mode of StateServer or SQLServer due to to the creation of network requests to retrieve the ids from the remote state server or sql server.

Comment: that was my big concern! So I guess it's better to hold the ids in session then fetch them from db tables? My main search page will need to know these ids and I don't want to have to fetch 2 ids from 2 tables every time the main page is searched.